# Shell Script to Run a python code with two different folders of The Same Numbered Files

Tags: python, shell

I have two folders and each contains files that has same numbering systems which is part of the file name. 
For example,

Folder 1 has:

```
  001file_read.txt, 002file_read.txt, until 650file_read.txt
```

Folder 2 has:

```
  001filtr.tsv, 002filtr.tsv, until 650filtr.tsv
```

I want to run a python code using shell script which basically runs like the following:

```
 python my_python_prog.py 001file_read.txt  001filtr.tsv
```

The problem is because I have a huge number of files of both folders. I want to find a way to run the command only once where it will automatically run file001 from folder1 to file001 to folder2 and file002 from folder1 to file002 from folder2 and so on until file650 of both folders. How can I do that using shell script?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance,

Comment: What shell are you using? Is it bash?

Answer (score 2):

If you have bash, you could use a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 

for i in {001..650}; do
    file_read=dir1/${i}file_read.txt
    file_filtr=dir2/${i}filtr.tsv
    if [[ -f $file_read ]] && [[ -f $file_filtr ]]; then
        python my_python_prog.py "$file_read" "$file_filtr"
    fi
done
```

This loops through all numbers from `000` to `650`, checks that both of the two files exists and executes the python command if they do.

If you don't have bash, you can achieve the same thing by making a few changes:

```
#!/bin/sh

while (( ++i <= 650 )); do
    n=$(printf '%03d' "$i")
    file_read=dir1/${n}file_read.txt
    file_filtr=dir2/${n}filtr.tsv
    if [ -f "$file_read" ] && [ -f "$file_filtr" ]; then
        python my_python_prog.py "$file_read" "$file_filtr"
    fi
done
```

Alternatively, you could modify your python script, perform the loop within it, and use `os.path.isfile()` to verify that both files exist. The advantage of this approach would be that you don't call your script 650 times.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more thing is possible if I do : file_read=dir1/${i}*.txt

Comment: You can't assign the result of a glob expansion to a variable like that but you could use an array: `file_read=( dir1/${i}*.txt )` then you can access each file like `"${file_read[0]}"`, `"${file_read[1]}"`, etc.

Comment: thanks a lot once again. I want to include a part of a code to check that the number of file_read is 4 or has to be 4 with an extension ,txt and for file_ filtr I want also to check the number of files to be 4 and the extension .tsv

Comment: It's not really clear what your exact requirements are from that comment but in any case, it's best not to keep changing your question. If your original problem is solved, you should accept this answer. You should have a go at solving your new problem yourself and if you get stuck, consider asking another question.